# soHARD IP core for ArcNET high Speed

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, fpga, spi

I am using a soHARD FPGA with a TI AM335x CPU. The controller communicates with the FPGA using SPI.

The issue I am having is that the bit-rate is set to 5 Mbps, but I could only get up to 50 kbps. The throughput for the ARCNET protocol is 40%.

Does any one have sample driver for the soHARD IP core, or can any one point me in the right direction?

Comment: Improved grammar.

Comment: according to the manual from sohard it's ARCNET pcore is parallel (like ISA) bus connection based. SPI is not even mentioned in the manual. perhaps you are using SPI<->ISA bridge slowing your interconnect 16 times minimum or even more.

Comment: according to the manual from sohard it's ARCNET pcore parallel bus operates on approx 2MHz frequency. make sure you have SPI configured at least 10 times faster = 20MHz